# Output not going into .txt file. CS HTML

Tags: javascript, c#, html, arrays

I created an array below to store the information required.
My expected output should be `smth` like:
John,2
May,3

The values beside the name is supposed to increment and replace the old value itself whenever the user presses on the specific button id.

Not sure why the information is not being written into the `data.txt` file.
Please advise. Thank you.

```js
@{
    var result = "";

    if (IsPost)
    {

        char[] delimiterChar = { ',' };

        var dataFile = Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/data.txt");

        string[] votesArr = File.ReadAllLines(dataFile);
        if (votesArr == null)
        {
            // Empty file.
            result = "The file is empty.";
        }

        string toWrite = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < votesArr.Length - 2; i += 2)
        {
            if (votesArr[i].Equals("Harry")) // Equals here is hardcoded, replace with parameter
            {
                votesArr[i + 1] = "" + (Int32.Parse(votesArr[i + 1]) + 1);
            }

            else if (votesArr[i].Equals("John")) // Equals here is hardcoded, replace with parameter
            {
                votesArr[i + 1] = "" + (Int32.Parse(votesArr[i + 1]) + 1);
            }

            else if (votesArr[i].Equals("May")) // Equals here is hardcoded, replace with parameter
            {
                votesArr[i + 1] = "" + (Int32.Parse(votesArr[i + 1]) + 1);
            }
            else if (votesArr[i].Equals("Jane")) // Equals here is hardcoded, replace with parameter
            {
                votesArr[i + 1] = "" + (Int32.Parse(votesArr[i + 1]) + 1);
            }

            toWrite += votesArr[i] + votesArr[i + 1];
        }
        File.WriteAllText(dataFile, toWrite);
        result = "Information is saved.";
    }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Elections</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" method="post">
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Harry</td>
                    <td><input id="Harry" name="submit" type="submit" value="Vote Harry" /></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td><input id="John" name="submit" type="submit" value="Vote John" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bryan</td>
                    <td><input id="Bryan" name="submit" type="submit" value="Vote Bryan" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jack</td>
                    <td><input id="Jack" name="submit" type="submit" value="Vote Jack" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div>
            @if (result != "")
            {
                <p>Result: @result</p>
            }
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You really should start with small console app to sort out your code that updates file... And then switch to handling web submissions... Doing so will help you see what you are reading from the file (since you can't search for "C# read CSV" for some reason) and writing to a file (which is very different from what you are reading at this point).

Answer (score 0):

You are not parsing the HTMl file. You are just reading it straight into the array.

Therefore each line in the array will contain the HTML syntax also, but you are not checking for that, you are just doing an .Equals("Harry") and it will never be equal to "Harry" because it's surrounded by the HTML markup.

You need to use something like [Angle Sharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) to parse up HTML and extract text.